# Удаление записи из БД через php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Суть вопроса: нужно напить кнопку для удаления записи из БД. 
Имеем форму:

```
<form class="lot-item__form" action="../lot.php?id=<?=$id;?>" method="post">
    <?php $classname = isset($error['com']) ? "--invalid" : "";?>
    <p class="lot-item__form-item <?=$classname;?>">
         <label for="com">Ваш комментарий</label>
         <textarea name="com" id="com" cols="33" rows="8"></textarea>
         <button type="submit" class="button">Комментировать</button>
         <button type="submit" name="del" class="button">Удалить пост</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Это форма отправки комментариев к посту в блоге. В этой же форме прикрутил кнопку удаления записи из БД. Настройки позволят удалить пост только автору, но вот как верно реализовать логику? Пробовал так:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if (isset($_POST['del'])) {
        $sql = 'DELETE * FROM post WHERE id = "' .$id. '";';
        $res = mysqli_query ($con, $sql);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, в чем ошибки и как сделать правильно? Спасибо.

Comment: Звездочка лишняя - DELETE FROM

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" name="del" class="button">Удалить пост</button>
```

сама по себе эта кнопка отправляет форму на сервер, в нее не заложен логический функционал, а в вашем случае это указать что данную запись нужно удалить

тут два способа вижу

1 Сделать чекбокс если он проставлен - удалить запись

2 Оставить вашу кнопку но в таком случае нужно будет в форму добавить скрытый input и на javascript отследить нажатие кнопки удаления записи. В этом случае javascript сам будет заполнять значение скрытого input.

Под скрытым input я понимаю `<input type="hidden" name="del" value="false"/>`

Answer (score -1):

Вы передали в форме `id` как *get*-параметр

Или используйте `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Или передавайте `value="$id"`

Comment: Переменная задана таким образом:
$id = intval($_GET['id']);